Is there a way to make Android Emulator use non-bundled qemu?
$ emulator -avd hd2
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Graphics backend: gfxstream
PANIC: CPU Architecture 'arm' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator, (the classic engine is deprecated!)

I have qemu-system-arm installed and should be able to launch the avd with that, but the AVD Manager always uses the bundled qemu binaries in $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-*
Is there a way I can use my existing qemu installation to launch avds with the android emulator?

I don't know but have doubts about replacement. Existing AVDs support hardware acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration , see AOSP docs: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/test/avd

@MorrisonChang is it possible to get any ARM/ARM64 devices working with the Android Emulator on an x86_64 host?

You should clarify what you are trying to do. Probably related: Which Android Virtual Device should be used to launch arm64-v8a APK on Windows?

@MorrisonChang He tries to run an ARM virtual device on an x86_64 computer, what more clarification do you need?

@PhilippLudwig I suspect OP was trying to run ARM code (ARM APK) on x86_64 and wasn't aware of support on certain AVDs which my link references.

Yes and no.
To explain the Android emulator is a downstream fork of QEMU which adds a whole bunch of things including a skin layer and a type of API pass through virtualisation for graphics. The original target machine "ranchu" cannot be run as is on the upstream QEMU emulator as it is missing the machine emulation details.
However Android AOSP images targeting the Cuttlefish virtual platform can be processed and then run manually using upstream QEMU. The Cuttlefish platform is based on VirtIO including the core GPU and input devices. The cuttlefish packages include binary builds of QEMU but you can also point the launch_cvd script at your own locally built QEMU.
You can find some instructions here that describes the various options.
Another option is to use cvs2img to convert the Android Cuttlefish images into standard raw disk images that caan then be run directly in QEMU or launched using the start-avm script.
The easiest way is to install the cuttlefish tools and
